# Translating Phrases with a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm doing a project where the goal is to create two programs. One program reads input from the user and translates it into Leetspeak, while the other converts Leetspeak back into English. Instead of spamming If statements or replace(" ", " ") I decided to try out using a dictionary to handle the translating.

Converting to Leetspeak was pretty easy. I just used a dictionary and a for loop.

**But, since the "letters" in Leetspeak sometimes contain more than one character I found it hard to convert it back without getting KeyErrors.**

Here's what I have so far.

```
phrase = raw_input('Enter a phrase: ')
output = []

KEY = {
    '4': 'A',
    '8': 'B',
    '(': 'C',
    '|)': 'D',
    '3': 'E',
    '|=': 'F',
    '6': 'G',
    '|-|': 'H',
    '!': 'I',
    '_|': 'J',
    '|<': 'K',
    '1': 'L',
    '|\/|': 'M',
    '|\|': 'N',
    '0': 'O',
    '|D': 'P',
    '(,)': 'Q',
    '|?': 'R',
    '5': 'S',
    '7': 'T',
    '|_|': 'U',
    '\/': 'V',
    '\/\/': 'W',
    '><': 'X',
    '`/': 'Y',
    '2': 'Z',
    ' ': ' ',
}

for char in phrase:
    if char in KEY:
        # This line works perfectly, since it only requires a single   
        # character
        print(KEY[char])
    else:
        while KEY[char] == False:
        # If I'm not getting KeyErrors I'm getting errors with appending
        # special characters or NoneType characters
        output = output.append(char)
    print(output)
    # I tried clearing the output after every iteration so that it could be
    # reused by the next char in phrase
    output = []

# Understand that all of the prints() are for testing the program. I'm   
# hoping to just have a single print() function at the end once everything  
# has been translated.
```

How can I convert all of these Leetspeak characters?

As for why I chose not to spam If statements and replace(" ", " ")'s, I like to challenge myself with new concepts. That being said I'm always open for *entirely* different ways to do this, if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe change your dictionary to have nested dicts as value when there is more than letter than starts with a character, ie for the char `|`, you would have `'|': {'|)':'D','|-|': 'H','|<': 'K','|\/|': 'M','|\|': 'N', etc...}`. this way, you can do a type check to see if there is more than one possibility, then parse the next characters accordingly.

Comment: @RNar Will you give me an example of how I can do the "type check" you suggested? I've only been working with Python for a couple weeks. I'm assuming I'll have to change something in the For loop I have.

Comment: my method is probably not the best to use then. I would suggest using @BlivetWidget's method because iterating through the keys and replacing them as such would be better. as i commented on his answer, i would sort the keys by reverse length (longest length first) to remove some ambiguity in keys. however, 2 V's in a row will always read as a W but i dont think that can really be avoided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward is easy, as you pointed out:

```
message = 'HALLOWEEN'
KEY_reversed = {v:k for k, v in KEY.items()}

>>> print(''.join(KEY_reversed[c] for c in message))
|-|4110\/\/33|\|
```

Going in the other direction is a little harder, but you could do it with `replace()`:

```
output = '|-|4110\\/\\/33|\\|'
for k, v in sorted(KEY.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True):
    if k in output:
        output = output.replace(k, v)

>>> output
'HALLOWEEN'
```

Without sorting, there could be ambiguities with characters like V and W, and they can be inconsistent ambiguities as dictionaries do not have a default sorting.

Comment: This doesn't work for *M* (`"|\/|"`). I get `"|V|"`.

Comment: you can improve this by iterating through `for k,v in sorted(KEY.items(),key = lambda x: len(x[0]),reverse = True)` which would then iterate through a list of the items with the longest keys first to remove ambiguities of keys for letters like M,V, and W

Comment: Good edit, gents, that solves the issue of arbitrary dictionary order.

Answer (score 0):

I would produce a list of keys, and sort them according to length (so '//' would be first in the list).  Once you have a reverse sorted list you can check the start of the string for your current key under test to do the reverse translation.

```
decodeString = ""
x = "! 4|\/| 31!73"
while len(x) > 0:
    for currentSearch in keys:
        if currentSearch in x[:len(currentSearch)]:
            print(currentSearch)
            decodeString += KEY[currentSearch]
            x = x[len(currentSearch):]

print( decodeString)
I AM ELITE
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. If you input `"! 4|\/| 31!73"`, you get `"I A"`.